# Linker script fails in Yocto build

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, linker-scripts

I am trying to use Bitbake tool for the cross-compilation of a Git project from x86 architecture to aarm64 architecture, but I am getting ld errors during the do_compile stage. I already checked `d/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/commandlinetool/1.0+gitAUTOINC+ce84868f3c-r0/recipe-sysroot/` and those missing files are actually exist! I don't know why bitbake complains about missing files. I also tried to add related paths to my custom recipe using `FILES_${PN} = ""` but this didn't help.

Also, I have `glibc` as a dependency in my recipe but this doesn't help:

`# dependencies DEPENDS += "glibc"  RDEPENDS_${PN} = "glibc"`

Errors I am getting are as the following:

```
| ~/bin/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/commandlinetool/1.0+gitAUTOINC+ce84868f3c-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
| ~/bin/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/commandlinetool/1.0+gitAUTOINC+ce84868f3c-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
| ~/bin/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/commandlinetool/1.0+gitAUTOINC+ce84868f3c-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: cannot find /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
```

Edit: Here is the recipe I am using. It depends on another Git project named "deviceaccess" (which my recipe for that project cross-compiled successfully):

```
LICENSE = "GPLv3 & Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=84dcc94da3adb52b53ae4fa38fe49e5d \
                    file://cmake/debian_package_templates/copyright;md5=0630bd8af87d19e6a57f9d1f9c5cf11f"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/ChimeraTK/CommandLineTools.git;protocol=https"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "ce84868f3c86f3f0790772a31fb5202a14f38fb8"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

# dependencies
DEPENDS += "glibc deviceaccess"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "glibc deviceaccess"
 
# cmake
inherit pkgconfig cmake

FILES_${PN} = ""

# Specify any options you want to pass to cmake using EXTRA_OECMAKE:
EXTRA_OEMAKE = ""
```

Comment: Please post the content of the recipe.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I added my recipe. My current recipe depends on "deviceaccess" which is based on another Git project. I already baked that recipe successfully

Comment: Is `deviceaccess` a private  recipe ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM No you can find it in https://github.com/ChimeraTK/DeviceAccess  Actually, there is a hierarchy of projects. This DeviceAccess tool depends on "cppext" and "exprtk-interface" (which again other projects). Do you think the problem can be from an already successfully cross-compiled recipe? Because I don't have any problem up to "DeviceAccess"

Comment: I need the deviceaccess Yocto recipe do try and compile your recipe .